# Vuejs, can't go to my signup link directly, it goes back to login

Tags: vue.js, authentication, vue-router, page-refresh, routerlink

https://github.com/ahcene-bouazza/P7_Bouazza_Ahcene_Grouporama.git
here is my github link for my project

- My issue is that when I am in login page, I clique on signup "inscription" it opens me the Signup page fine, but when I refresh the browser it goes back to login page
- Other issue is when I type my signup directly on my browser adresse "http://localhost:8080/signup" it does not go there but it goes to login page http://localhost:8080/

[login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHH3n.png)
[signup page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lLDt.png)

Thank you very much if you can find a solution for me it will be really much apreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You in `App.vue` on `mounted()` call redirect `this.$router.push('/')`, but you have `this.user.id` only after login, without user data you call redirect to login page. It's incorrect. Just read documentaion [Official docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#navigation-guards) and you will understand how to correct use protected routes.

Example `router/index.js`:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.name !== 'Login' &&  to.name !== 'Signup' && !this.user.id == 0) next({ name: 'Login' })
  else next()
})
```

instead of `App.vue`

```
if (this.user.id == 0 && this.$router.currentRoute.path != '/') {
        this.$router.push('/')
      }
```